# SendMessage() and PostMessage() proper usage

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got a problem with using SendMessage() and PostMessage() properly. The thing what i'm trying to  do is `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);` in my window procedure

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_USER:
        break;
    case WM_USER + 1:
        break;
    default:
        if (grid.ProcessEvent(wmId, wmEvent))
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Im not really sure why it doesn't work, maybe someone could help. I'm sure SendMessage(...) is called but it doesn't affect to run WndProc with my arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The case label `case WM_USER + 1:` is nested in the inner case statement (that switches on `wmId`).  It needs to be moved out to the `switch (message)` case statement, so it is at the same level of nesting as  `case WM_COMMAND:` and `case WM_DESTROY:`.

The above also applies to `case WM_USER:`.

Answer (score 0):

SendMessage is specified to not return until the receiver window has processed the message - which it cannot do as you're inside your own WndProc and messaging yourself. This is one of those cases where you should be using PostMessage.